# Install two MTAs on Gentoo

Tags: postfix, gentoo, email

Im migrating my Qmail/Vpopmail Install to MySQL/Postfix and want to test Postfix on different Ports than the current qmail Installation and bit by bit merge the config and Database - is there any way to Install both MTAs on the same Gentoo System or do i really have to take the long way using Virtualization/Chroot and the like?

When trying to emerge the Packages of course block each other.

Answer (score 1):

Postfix doesn't care; it can be run on any ports you want just by editing its `master.cf` file. Gentoo's blocking the package is entirely artificial and unnecessary. (And why on earth are you using Gentoo for this?!?!?)

Comment: +1 for the questioning of using Gentoo in this particular case.

Comment: Sure, its possible to compile and install the package manually, i was looking for an efficient way to migrate the MTAs - as said: merge postfix, setup config, unmerge vpopmail/qmail.

While i agree on your criticism that Gentoo's blocking is unnecessary to a certain degree, i guess you dont want to start debating the use of Gentoo in a Server environment!?
My Dedicated Server has ever been running Gentoo since 2004 and i really prefer its package management to most other Distros (except *BSD) - never troubled me except in this particular, somewhat exotic case.